# Format Excel Column To YYYY-MM-DD

Tags: date, excel-2007

I need this to be I guess "Custom" formatting of the cells, as I can not do it via VBA.  How can a cell, by default, show the date in the yyyy-mm-dd format?

Comment: To my knowledge, I don't believe there is a way to format as you have stated. Some formatting of dates can be changed by changing your computer's regional settings, but none of them offer Year first formatting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just click on the column and **Format** > **Cells...**

[image]